# iOS accessibility hint not being spoken on an Text Field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, accessibility, uiaccessibility

We have created a very simple app using storyboards which contains a single screen with a Text Field. I have set the Accessibility Label and Hint on the Text Field however when I deploy the app to my iPhone, Voiceover only reads out the Label not the Hint.

I am assuming this must be a bug, has anyone seen similar behaviour?

Note we were developing using Xcode 4.2 under Lion and deploying to an iPhone running 5.0.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

without looking at your code, that's kind of hard; this article is quite in depth and explains Voiceover, Labels, and Hints very well:
http://mattgemmell.com/2010/12/19/accessibility-for-iphone-and-ipad-apps/

Comment: Hi, this is a great link, thanks, but it implies hints should be spoken and in the case of setting a hint on a Text Field the hint is not being spoken. I've raised this as a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this behavior on iOS 5.0 and 5.1, but it appears to be fixed in iOS 6.0.